# Scripting mouse movements in c++ using <Windows.h>

Tags: c++, winapi, mouse

I am programming a script to move a mouse in a circular motion with some extra parameters as user input. Below you can the the snippet with the function i was working on. The cursor sticks to a single point and keeps at it until the last for loop is over and the rest of my program runs. What is wrong?

```
void move_mouse_circle()
{

    int steps = 500; // init default values everything
    int radius = 200;
    float degree = 0;
    bool add_inconsistency;
    char add_incon_answ;
    
    std::cout << "Please, provide the amount of steps for smoothness (default is at " << steps << "): ";
    std::cin >> steps;
    std::cout << "Please, provide the radius of the desired circle (default is at " << radius << "): ";
    std::cin >> radius;
    std::cout << "Do you want to add inconsistency to mimic human input? y/n: ";
    std::cin >> add_incon_answ;
    if (add_incon_answ == 'y')
    {
        add_inconsistency = true;
    }
    else
    {
        add_inconsistency = false;
    }
    
    /* float x_coord;
    float y_coord; */
    float *x_coord = new float[steps];
    float *y_coord = new float[steps];
    
    float degree_increm = 360 / steps; // define degree increment per step
    
    for (int i = 0; i < steps; i++)
    {
        // float radian = degree_increm / (2 * M_PI); // converting degrees to radians
        x_coord[i] = radius * cos(degree);
        y_coord[i] = radius * sin(degree);
    
        degree = +degree_increm;
    }
    
    std::cout << "Starting in 3 seconds... ";
    Sleep(1000);
    std::cout << "2 seconds... ";
    Sleep(1000);
    std::cout << "1 second... " << std::endl;
    Sleep(990);
    
    float curr_x_coord; // define var for current cursor pos for x axis
    float curr_y_coord; // define var for current cursor pos for y axis
    
    POINT curr_cursor_p; // POINT typedef contains x and y long
    GetCursorPos(&curr_cursor_p);
    curr_x_coord = curr_cursor_p.x;
    curr_y_coord = curr_cursor_p.y;
    
    for (int u = 0; u < steps; u++)
    {
        SetCursorPos(x_coord[u] + curr_x_coord, y_coord[u] + curr_y_coord);
        if (add_inconsistency == true)
        {
            float millis = 2 + ((1 + rand() % 50) / 100);
            Sleep(millis);
        }
        else
        {
            Sleep(2);
        }
    };
    
    delete[] x_coord;
    delete[] y_coord;

};
```

I have tried changing the parameters and simplifying the expressions etc., but it does not work still. I want to retain the mathematical approach, so to use the math equations to solve this programming problem.

Comment: Could the mouse be moving too fast for you to actually see it interum?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please learn how to create a [mre].

Comment: I altered the Sleep() to check for that and that was not the reason. The movement actually takes good 2-3 seconds depending on the amout of steps.

Comment: Could you print out the float values in your array? To see if it's actually occupied? Also SetCursorPos takes int values not floats.

Comment: I will correct for the int type and double check the array, it worked last time. BRB, thanks for the contribution.

Comment: All the values in the array with points on the circumference were 200 for x and 0 for y values. Same as the input radius...

Comment: As it turns out, the degree_increm variable is set to zero always. Trying to figure out why.

Comment: Fixed it by going from float degree_increm = 360 / steps; to float degree_increm = float(360) / float(steps); Thank you all for the contribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo with the increment operator: `degree = +degree_increm;` should be `degree += degree_increm;`. Beyond that the main problems with this code are about units and types.

The standard trigonometry functions use radians as units. Since your code never deals with angles inputted by the user, there is no reason to use degrees anywhere. Humans like degrees, computer programs like radians. So you should rename `degree_increm` to `angle_increm` and calculate it by dividing two pi by the number of steps.

The other errors involve the difference between floating point types and integer types. In particular integer division is a fundamentally different operation than floating point division. So for example `float degree_increm = 360 / steps;` is not doing what you think it is doing because `360` and `steps` are both integers. Decide which of your variables are logically floats and which are logically integers, define them as such, and explicitly cast when the two kinds of numbers interact with each other.

Another type related issue, which I did not fix below, is that unless you have a specific reason to be using single precision floats you should prefer doubles; [see here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/188721/when-do-you-use-float-and-when-do-you-use-double).

Code below, if you need it:

```
void move_mouse_circle()
{
    int steps = 500;
    int radius = 200;
    float angle = 0.0f;
    bool add_inconsistency;
    char add_incon_answ;

    std::cout << "Please, provide the amount of steps for smoothness (default is at " << steps << "): ";
    std::cin >> steps;
    std::cout << "Please, provide the radius of the desired circle (default is at " << radius << "): ";
    std::cin >> radius;
    std::cout << "Do you want to add inconsistency to mimic human input? y/n: ";
    std::cin >> add_incon_answ;

    if (add_incon_answ == 'y')
    {
        add_inconsistency = true;
    } else
    {
        add_inconsistency = false;
    }

    float* x_coord = new float[steps];
    float* y_coord = new float[steps];

    const auto pi = std::acosf(-1.0);
    float angle_increm = (2.0f * pi) / static_cast<float>(steps);

    for (int i = 0; i < steps; i++)
    {
        x_coord[i] = radius * cos(angle);
        y_coord[i] = radius * sin(angle);

        angle += angle_increm;
    }

    std::cout << "Starting in 3 seconds... ";
    Sleep(1000);
    std::cout << "2 seconds... ";
    Sleep(1000);
    std::cout << "1 second... " << std::endl;
    Sleep(990);

    float curr_x_coord; // define var for current cursor pos for x axis
    float curr_y_coord; // define var for current cursor pos for y axis

    POINT curr_cursor_p; // POINT typedef contains x and y long
    GetCursorPos(&curr_cursor_p);
    curr_x_coord = static_cast<float>(curr_cursor_p.x);
    curr_y_coord = static_cast<float>(curr_cursor_p.y);

    for (int u = 0; u < steps; u++)
    {
        SetCursorPos(static_cast<int>(x_coord[u] + curr_x_coord),
            static_cast<int>(y_coord[u] + curr_y_coord));
        if (add_inconsistency == true)
        {
            DWORD millis = 2 + ((1 + rand() % 50) / 100);
            Sleep(millis);
        } else
        {
            Sleep(2);
        }
    };

    delete[] x_coord;
    delete[] y_coord;

};
```